# Postgres violates primary key constraint

Tags: postgresql

We encountered a very strange bug in our production PostgresDB (v.10.19).

We have a table that is defined like that:

```
create table testtable (
id            varchar not null constraint testtable_pkey primary key,
valid         boolean not null,
last_modified timestamp
);

create unique index testtable_id_uindex on testtable (id);
```

Now my problem is, that id field is not unique anymore even so the definition was not changed.

The query

```
select id || '_', count(*) count, max(last_modified), min(last_modified)
from testtable
group by id || '_' 
having count(*) > 1;
```

is returning hundreds of duplicated entries. But if i remove the concatenation of `|| '_'` I only get 3 wrong entries. So I guess this has something to do with Postgres encoding?

I already searched the internet and found some bugs that are referencing a 9.6 version of Postgres and also some answers where the sequence was out of sync but in my case I do not use a sequence but generate the id's manually.

If you could give me some hints what I have to search for would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you populate `testtable`?

Comment: None of this seems to make sense. I have never seen a PK constraint violated like this. I certainly cannot reproduce any of this. (And it makes no sense to have a PK *and* an UNIQUE index on `id` to begin with.) Maybe confusion among multiple tables named "testtable" in multiple schemas?

Comment: Did your operating system recently receive any updates? If yes, this could be caused by a glibc update. See [Locale data changes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes) in the Postgres Wiki. But I agree with Erwin: two unique indexes on a single column make no sense.

Comment: What is the encoding, ctype, and collation?

Comment: Have you been running with fsync = off?